# My IP seems to be blocked by web hosting server

Tags: hosting, ip, blocking, shared

I have a strange problem, I just installed my php web site on a shared hosting, all services were working fine. But after configuring my app I just could visit my web site only once, other attempts gives:

> "The server is taking too long to respond.".

But from other IP i can access, but only once, it seems all ip addressess beeing blocked after first visit(even ftp and other services get down, no access at all from the IP), can anyone help to explore this problem ? I don't think that it's my app problem, the app works fine on my local PC.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to try would be a traceroute to determine where your traffic is being blocked.

In a windows command prompt:

```
tracert www.yoursharedhostingserver.com
```

Comment: he says all other services are active, so a tracert would probably work just fine, its the http service thats not responding.

Comment: the way I read it, he says that other ports go down as well: "(even ftp and other services get down, no access at all from the IP"

Comment: but yeah, I agree that we need more information. eg: the URL so we can look at it.

Comment: Currently giving me a zero-sized page.

Comment: geofftnz sorry, i can't give access to backend, frontend is empty in the main time, but i can try to explain the situation more in etails.

Comment: Geofftnz , actually after all first visits from any IP all services go down for the IPs, i think there is infinity loop in my code and then server blocks the thread binded to the IP(apache, php ...if this is the way). what do u do think about this ? is it possible ? but i am not sure about that.

Comment: hmmm... I'm out of ideas sorry.

Comment: geofftnz, thats alot for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that if you can access it once that its actually working.  The problem is more than likely in the php code than in the server.

Comment: I was thinking that its my code problem, but it's working fine on my local PC(windows XP), should work properly on Linux as well, i tried to clean browser session, cookies and also tried all browsers, no help.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, trying to access this address gives this:

> Fatal error: Class 'mainController'
>   not found in
>   /home/myicms/public_html/core/application/crApplication.class.php
>   on line 181

I have tried it multiple times and it didn't block me. It might be that You have already solved this problem.

As far as I know, the behavior described by You could only be explained by a badly configured intelligent firewall. It may have been misconfigured by Your host.

If You visit a site at a certain host and suddenly You cannot access an ftp on this host, then it's either a (really bad) firewall or a (very mean) site that explicitly adds a firewall rule to ignore that address.

Some things that You might look into:

It might be something with identd too. What was the service You have configured on Your host? Was it by any chance any kind of server-controll panel (that might have an ability to controll a firewall)?

Is the blockade permanent, or does it go off after 24h, or does it only go off after rebooting the server? Does restarting some services makes the blockade go off?

Did You install any software that "protects Your server from portscanning"? It might be a bit too aggressive.

I wish You good luck in finding a source of this problem!