# mod_security blocks IP when script fails with error?

Tags: shared-hosting, blocking

I have problem with blocking my IP, i installed php application on shared hosting and tryed to run it, but it gave some errors, then i tried to refresh the page, but after 3 rd attempt my ip got blocked to all ports. No available service(ftp,ssh). Apache mod_securty blocks it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this problem by any chance related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708337/can-php-code-break-down-shared-hosting-services-for-the-particular-ip) or [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708163/my-ip-seems-to-be-blocked-by-web-hosting-server)?

Could You *please* post the errors, the php version, the address of the site so me and folks can examine it?

What was application have You configured?